Where can I find a proof that the crossing number of a knot/link is a knot invariant?
Where can I find a proof that the crossing number of a knot/link is a knot invariant?
I know that this is in fact a true statement when you consider that the presentation of the knot is the one with the minimum number of crossings.
It is also obvious that Reidemeister moves of type I and II change this quantity thus this is not an invariant under Reidemeister moves.
Can anyone help me find a proof of such a statement? Thanks

I think it is almost tautological.
Let $K$ be some knot with some Diagram.
Let $K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4,K_5,\cdots$ be Equivalent knots with various Diagrams , according to various transformations.
Among all these , we have some knot Diagram $K_k$ which has the least number (x) of crossings.
Define "Minimal Crossing Number" $C(K)=C(K_k)=x$
Naturally , $x=C(K_1)=C(K_2)=C(K_3)=C(K_4)=C(K_5)=\cdots$
Now when we transform $K$ to some Equivalent knot , which is already in the earlier list of Equivalent knots , then that Equivalent knot too can be transformed to $K_k$ where $C(K_k)=x$
Hence "Minimal Crossing Number" is invariant.
